# Jqgrid context menu for multiple selected rows

Tags: jqgrid, contextmenu

I'm using jqgrids contextmenu plugin as descriped in [this forum post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/jquery-ui-compatible-version-of-jquery-contextmenu-js/).

My question is: How can I get all selected rows, when the grid paramter 'multiselect' is 'true? Background: I would like to apply a context menu action for all select rows.

Thanks for your anwsers,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the selected rows on jqGrid, you can use this code:

```
$('#yourGrid').jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow");
```

This will return an array containing the ids of your selected rows.